# PHP - accessing locked row in an Oracle table

Tags: php, ajax, oracle, concurrency, locking

I have a web application which needs to send multiple Ajax request to a PHP page (backend.php)

There is an **Oracle** table, let's say *T1* with 2 int fields *min* and *max* (for this example is enough, actually it's a bit more complex).

Backend.php needs to read *mix* and *max*, update these values (let's say min += 2, max += 3), then return min and max via some JSON.

In this case I can't use Oracle Sequences (because in the real application there are N rows).

I want to put a **lock on the row**, to avoid different Ajax calls reading the same values from the row.

I tried to run (via PHP's OCI) something like `SELECT a, b FROM t1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` but it seems not to work, 2 Ajax calls sometimes return the same A and B values.

How can I make locks working? Is there a better way? Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you omit the `SKIP LOCKED` clause?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Anyway, is it the right way to put a lock on a row?

Comment: What are you doing to ensure that a particular PHP session maps to exactly one database session for the duration of the time that you want to lock the row in the database?  That is generally not how three-tier applications are built.  Based on your description of the problem, it appears that the session holding the lock is getting released back to the connection pool too early.

Comment: I can't spot obvious errors. I've used `FOR UPDATE` myself (without `SKIP LOCKED`) and it works fine: concurrent queries get queued until the table is released. Of course, you need to ensure you don't release until you're done.

Comment: The lock should be released at the end of the PHP script, or after a commit, isn't it? I'll try again without FOR UPDATE. Thank you.

Comment: My fault. I had to put in my backend.php

    `session_write_close()`

...otherwise my browser hanged. I called it _before_ the query `SELECT... FOR UPDATE`. Now I've put it after testing the result of this query, and it seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need explicit locks at all. A simple

```
update T1 set min=min+2, max=max+3 where ...
```

will put locks on the affected rows automatically.

You may need anther select to return the updated values (or use RETURNING in PL/SQL)